# Is a DOM Text Node guaranteed to not be interpreted as HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xss

Does anyone know whether a DOM `Node` of type `Text` is guaranteed not be interpreted as HTML by the browser?

More details follow.

**Background**

I'm building a simple web comment system for a friend, and I've been thinking about XSS attacks.  I don't think filtering or escaping HTML tags is a very elegant solution--it's too easy to come up with a convolution that will slip past the filter.  The fundamental issue is that I want to guarantee that, for certain pieces of content (i.e. the content that random unauthenticated web users POST), the browser *never* tries to interpret or run the content.

**A plain(text) start**

The first thought that came to mind is just to use `Content-Type: text/plain`, but this has to apply to a whole page.  You can put a plaintext `IFRAME` in the middle of a page, but it's ugly, and it creates focus problems if the user clicks into the frame.

**innerText/textContent/JQuery**

It turns out that there are some browser-specific (`innerText` in IE, `textContent` in FF, Safari, etc.) attributes that, when set, are required to create a single `Text` node.

JQuery tries to avoid the difference in browser-specific attributes, by implementing a single function `text(val)` that skips the browser-specific attributes and goes directly to `document.createTextNode(text)`, which, as you can guess, creates a `Text` node.

**W3 DOM `Text` `Node`s**

So I think this is close to what I want, it looks good--`Text` nodes can't have children, and it appears like they can't be interpreted as HTML.  But I am not 100% sure from the official docs.

- Interface `Node`: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247
- Interface `Text`: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772
- `textContent`: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent

The part from `textContent` is particularly encouraging, because it says "on setting, no parsing is performed either, the input string is taken as pure textual content."  But is this fundamental to all `Text` nodes, or only nodes on which you set `textContent`?  This probably seems like a dumb quibble, but it might be important because *IE doesn't support `textContent`* (see above).

**Back around to the initial question**

Can anyone confirm/reject that this will work?  That is, that a w3 DOM compliant browser will *never* interpret a `Text` node as HTML, no matter what the content?  I'd be extremely grateful to have this tormenting little uncertainty resolved.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is confirmed, to the extent that for what ever browser it wasn't, that browser would have a *serious* defect. A text node that rendered anything but text would be a contradiction. By using document.createTextNode("some string"); and appending that node, the string is *guaranteed* to be rendered as text.

Answer (score -1):

> I don't think filtering or escaping HTML tags is a very elegant solution--it's too easy to come up with a convolution that will slip past the filter

That is absolutely untrue, filtering > to &gt; and < to &lt; will completely stop any HTML injection.

Comment: I'm basing my paranoia on:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728/will-html-encoding-prevent-all-kinds-of-xss-attacks

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/

Comment: @surprise_ wrong. there are many other injection techniques, from encoding tricks, to attribute injection, JavaScript, CSS, etc