# How to curry a function that takes an options object as argument rather than several distinct arguments?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, currying, ramda.js

I have been looking into partial application and currying over the last few days.

I'm wondering how could I use these concepts with a function that only takes one `options` object as argument.

```
const myFunc = options => {
  const options.option1 = options.option1 || 'default value';
  const options.option2 = options.option2 || 'another default value';
  // ... etc, it takes about 5 more options, all of which have a
  // default fall-back value if not supplied

  return doSometing(options);
}
```

In that case, I don't feel good changing the `myFunc` signature and pass every option as a separate argument because it's a pain to remember the order in which the options must be supplied.

I'd like to stick with a functional style and avoid instantiating objects with `new ...` just to keep state; I have a hunch this can be achieved with partial application. It keeps things simpler when it's time for testing, or to instantiate.

But then, I don't know how to do partial application properly without separate arguments.

How would you handle this refactor?

Comment: If you only have one argument, then there's nothing to curry...

Comment: See [Can we set persistent default parameters which remain set until explicitly changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466657/can-we-set-persistent-default-parameters-which-remain-set-until-explicitly-chang)

Comment: @elclanrs: Absolutely.  This is some other, perhaps interesting, form of partial application.

Comment: It's a wrapper around request which itself takes a bazillion options via its options object.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the equivalent of currying a function taking an option object would be the same as how to handle defaults. Consider this as a partial applier:

```
myFuncWithMyOptions(myFunc, myOptions) {
  return function(options) {
    return myFunc(Object.assign({}, myOptions, options));
  }
}
```

If you want the options in `myOptions` not be be overridden by those in `options` simply swap the two arguments to `Object.assign`

Comment: And if there are some options properties which have no default and are therefore required, you could extend this by either supplying a list of the names of the required properties, or by including them in `myOptions` with a value that signals that a call made without them is incomplete (`undefined` is possible if that can never be the value, or some `Symbol` attached to `myFuncWithMyOptions`.)  If an incomplete object is sent, you can return a newly wrapped version of the original function with an extended set of defaults, and a reduced set of required fields.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, that might make debugging easier as the call would fail earlier. But it wouldn't change its effect.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that this would then work like other forms of partial application.  If you don't supply all the required parameters, you simply get back a new function that will merge its options with the previous ones (and the defaults) and call the original function with them (assuming you've now supplied all the required ones.)

Comment: @DanD. I think Scott is referring to currying here. To curry a usual function, you need to know its arity, to "curry" a option-object function you need to know which properties it expects.

Comment: If you are permitted to supply values for the same option more than once or more than one option at a time then there is no fixed arity even if there is a fixed number of properties. Then it isn't reasonable to curry but rather one has to keep explicitly partially applying.

Comment: I'll make another answer out of my idea.  It's probably easier to see that way.

Answer (score 2):

Following on Dan D's answer and the comments, this technique would let you partially apply such a function repeatedly until all the required fields are supplied:

```
const vals = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

const addDefaults = (() => {
  const req = Symbol();
  const addDefaults = (defaults, fn) => (options) => {
    const params = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    return (vals(params).includes(req)) 
      ? addDefaults(params, fn)
      : fn(params);
  };
  addDefaults.REQUIRED = req;
  return addDefaults;
})();


const order = addDefaults({
  color: addDefaults.REQUIRED,
  size: addDefaults.REQUIRED,
  giftWrap: false,
  priority: false
}, (opts) => 
   `${opts.size}, ${opts.color}, ${opts.giftWrap ? '' : 'no'} wrap, priority: ${opts.priority}`
);

order({color: 'Red', size: 'Medium'}); // "Medium, Red, no wrap, priority: false"

const orderLarge = order({size: 'Large'}); // Options -> String
orderLarge({color: 'Blue'}); // "Large, Blue, no wrap, priority: false"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is connected with partial application. What exactly does `myFunc` do actually?

- it sets a couple of optional default values
- it invokes another function

This is not much. And yet two problems arise:

- the function composition is hard coded and hidden in the body of `myFunc`
- it doesn't get apparent from the function signature which default values are overwritten

Simply put, a "proper" function reveals its functionality by its signature. So let's get rid of the `myFunc` wrapper:

```js
const options = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: true,
  bat: "",
  baz: []
};

// function composition

const comp = (...fs) => x => fs.reduceRight((acc, f) => f(acc), x);

// applicator for partial application with right section

const _$ = (f, y) => x => f(x) (y); // right section

// `Object` assignment

const assign = o => p => Object.assign({}, o, p);

// specific function of your domain

const doSomething = o => (console.log(o), o);

// and run (from right-to-left)

comp(doSomething, _$(assign, {baz: [1, 2, 3], bat: "abc"})) (options);
```

Now you can exactly see what is going on without having to look into the function bodies. The property order of the options `Object` doesn't matter either.

A remark on `_$`. It has this odd name because I prefer a visual name over a textual one in this particular case. Given the function `sub = x => y => x - y`, `_$(sub, 2)` simply means `x => x - 2`. This is called the right section of the partially applied `sub` function, because the "left" argument is still missing.

Comment: Dude this answer was a hammerblow holy cow. I've done a lot of reading on fp (and just recently tried to implement strictly) but I've mostly just come across theory and not much implementation. From your answer alone I learned: not everything needs to be curried; sometimes partial application makes more sense, an applicator is a function that takes a function and applies it to a value, and how to work with defaults. Incredible answer! I can't believe it doesn't have more upvotes!!!