# Pass in any number of arguments into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to pass in any number of arguments into a function and then be able to use those arguments later. I know I can pass in default arguments but I don't know what to declare in my function.

For example,

```
function test(????) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
}

test(a="a", b="b", c="c")
```

I'm also challenged by being given this function and to make as little changes to the var declarations as much as possible. So here, variables, a, b, and c are declared and I'm not able to edit these variables. I should be able to pass in arguments that will then know to assign itself to these variables.

```
function test(???) {
  var a,b,c
  if (a>b){
    c = a + b
  }
}

test(a=2,b=3)
```

Comment: Maybe check this out? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to define any arguments in the function parameters. All you need to do is access javascript's built in `arguments` object.

So your code could look like the following:

```
function test() {
    var a = arguments[0];
    var b = arguments[1];
    var c = arguments[2];

    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}

test("a", "b", "c");
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: This was great! What I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Using an array is a good idea, but in the interest of completeness...

#### The ES6 way!

If you're able to support ES6 features, the [spread operator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK79eL16zUAhWkx4MKHc5OCdQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FSpread_operator&usg=AFQjCNFSwhTca4g8MUFTmTCFQJpXEzfGWw&sig2=jW9c8BtKnujj7o8_TM_CHQ) combined with the arguments keyword is a neat way to get around that:

```
function anyNumber() {
  console.log(...arguments); // ->  1 2 3 4

  let argsAsArray = [0, ...arguments, 5]; // now they're an array

  argsAsArray.forEach(s => console.log(s)); // -> 0 1 2 3 4 5
};

anyNumber(1,2,3,4);
```

There are a lot of cool things you can do with the spread operator, especially with object and parameter destructuring.

Comment: Yea, I think destructuring was the best way to go for me in this case

Answer (score 1):

you could pass in an object or an array:

```
function test1([a, b, c]) {
   // ...
}
test1([1, 2, 3]);

function test2({ a, b, c }) {
   // ...
}
test2({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(input) {
  console.log(input.a);
  console.log(input.b);
  console.log(input.c);
}

test({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array or an object.

In that array add as many arguments you want.

```js
function test(arr) {
   console.log(arr.a);
   console.log(arr.b);
   console.log(arr.c);
}

arr = {}
   
arr.a = "a";
arr.b = "b";
arr.c = "c";
    
k = test(arr);
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, except I'm working with a function where the variables are pre-set, meaning I can't change the var declarations. I have to make sure what I pass into the function, my arguments will need to connect with their corresponding declarations inside the function.

Comment: @jamesvphan That's not a problem just assign those to a newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

Given `javascript` at updated Question, you can define default parameters within `()` following function name.

```js
function test(a = 2, b = 3) {
  let c;
  if (a > b) {
    c = a + b
  } else {
    c = 0
  }
  console.log(c);
}

test(); // 0

test(4); // 7
```

See also [Can we set persistent default parameters which remain set until explicitly changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466657/can-we-set-persistent-default-parameters-which-remain-set-until-explicitly-chang)

Comment: I think this is what I need, but the code snippet is giving me an error from the fn(...opts) function you had

Comment: @jamesvphan The error was probably due to use of object rest `{...opts.map((prop, index)}`. Object rest  `{a, b, ...rest}` is available using `--javascript-harmony` flag at chromium, chrome; or using `babel` standalone. Will enable `babel` at stacksnippets

Comment: @jamesvphan See updated stacksnippets