# Javascript callback for two functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

Is there a way to achieve the code bellow with Javascript (ES6)?

If yes, how can I do it? I try this example, but it didn't work.

```
const funcA = (callback, arg1) => {
  console.log("Print arg1: " + arg1); /* Print arg1: argument1 */
  let x = 0;
  x = callback(x, );
  return x;
}

const funcB = (x, prefix) => {
  console.log("Print prefix: " + prefix); /* Print prefix: PREFIX_ */
  x = x + 1;
  return x;
}

/* Exec function funcA */
let x = funcA(funcB( ,"PREFIX_"), "argument1");
console.log("Value of x: " + x); /* Value of x: 1 */
```

Comment: you have empty arguments and leading comma. what result do you expect?

Comment: I know that. But what I mean with the blank space and comma is that the arguments are pass in different time.

Comment: Partial application - that is what I want to know! My example shows that. (see the accepted answer).

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima Define `x` as a default parameter `funcA(x = () => funcB(x = 0 ,"PREFIX_"), "argument1");`

Comment: @guest271314 I got this error from console with your example: ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `x' before initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial application is not yet possible in js. You need another arrow function that acts as a callback:

```
funcA(x => funcB(x ,"PREFIX_"), "argument1");
```

To call that you don't need that extra comma:

```
x = callback(x)
```

Somewhen [this proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-partial-application/blob/master/README.md) might allow to write this:

```
 funcA( funcB(?, "PREFIX_"), "argument1")
```

Comment: Nice reference to the proposal +1

Comment: @pedro glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach with a defined placeholder as symbol to identify the parameter which is not yet set.

It features a `this` object which is bind to the calling function for further check and evaluation.

If the combined array of [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and `this.arg` has no more `placeholder` items, the function is called with parameters and return the function call.

If not, the new arguments array is bind to the function and returnd.

> `[?]` denotes the placeholder symbol
>
> ```
>  funcB    x    prefix       this.args        args       action
> -------  ---  ---------  -------------  --------------  ------------------------------
> 1. call  [?]  "PREFIX_"                 [?], "PREFIX_"  return calling fn w/ bound args
> 2. call   0      [?]     [?], "PREFIX_"  0,  "PREFIX_"  return fn call with args
> 3. call   0   "PREFIX_"                                 return 1
> ```

(Of course it could be a bit shorter and delegated to another function, but it's a proof of concept.)

```js
function funcA(callback, arg1) {
    console.log('funcA', callback, arg1)
    return callback(0, placeholder);
}

function funcB(x, prefix) {
    var args = this && this.args || [],
        temp = Array.from(arguments);

    console.log('funcB', isPlaceholder(x) ? '[?]' : x, isPlaceholder(prefix) ? '[?]' : prefix);

    // placeholder part
    if (temp.some(isPlaceholder)) {
        temp.forEach((a, i) => isPlaceholder(a) && i in args || (args[i] = a));
        return args.some(isPlaceholder)
            ? funcB.bind({ args })
            : funcB(...args);
    }

    // origin function body
    return x + 1;
}

const
    placeholder = Symbol('placeholder'),
    isPlaceholder = v => v === placeholder;

console.log("Value of x: " + funcA(funcB(placeholder, "PREFIX_"), "argument1"));
```

Comment: nice! +1. Could you explain some details of your example? 1. In funcB, where it come the variable "arguments"? It's a default parameter for functions? 2. In the output, it was printed "funcB 0 [?]" and "funcB 0 PREFIX_", that means funcB was called twice. So the first time it called for binding funcB in funcA, the second time was for returned funcB(...args)? 3. The first call for funcB was made in "funcA(funcB(placeholder, "PREFIX_"), "arguments")", the second call was made in "return callback(0, placeholder)"?

Comment: every function in Javascript supplies [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), which is an array like object with all paramters of the actual function. it is right, the calling series, as you stated, but the function is called three times. it always checks if there is no placeholder in the `arguments` list. if so, it returns the origin function body evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to define a default parameter that is a function for the first parameter passed to `funcA` and use `var` to define `x` when `funcA` is called

```js
const funcA = (callback, arg1) => {
  console.log("Print arg1: " + arg1);
  let x = 0;
  x = callback(x, arg1);
  return x;
}

const funcB = (x, prefix) => {
  console.log("Print prefix: " + prefix);
  x = x + 1;
  return x;
}

/* Exec function funcA */
var x = funcA(x = () => funcB(x = 0 ,"PREFIX_"), "argument1");
console.log("Value of x: " + x);
```

Comment: If you see in my example, I didn't pass the arg1 as argument to callback. Would it make difference?

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima Why did you not pass the `arg1` argument? How does that change the expected result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It this example it's not so clear, but the fact that I isolate the arguments in funcB turn the code modular. In your example, arg1 is part of funcA, but I want funcA be immutable. That way, if a want pass a funcC instead of funcB to funcA, it won't depend on the variable arg1. I hope be clearly about that hehe.

Comment: Do you mean that where `arg1` is not specifically passed `prefix` will still be defined at `funcB`? That is, a default value will be set, and the default value can be the adjacent defined argument?

Comment: From this "Do you mean that where arg1 is not specifically passed prefix will still be defined at funcB?", yes!

Comment: See my code again! I edited and add the output from the console.log. The "PREFIX_" is printed inside funcB and arg1 is printed inside funcA!

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima  You can set `prefix` as a default parameter at `funcN`; e.g., `const fn = ({x = 0, prefix = "PREFIX_"} = {x:0, prefix:"PREFIX_"}) => {
  console.log(x, prefix)
}; fn(); fn({x:2});` see also [Can we set persistent default parameters which remain set until explicitly changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466657/can-we-set-persistent-default-parameters-which-remain-set-until-explicitly-chang)