# Partial functions with bind

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind, currying, partial-application

So recently I discovered that you can do partial functions/currying with js using bind.
For example:

```
const foo = (a, b, c) => (a + (b / c))
foo.bind(null, 1, 2) //gives me (c) => (1 + (2 / c))
```

However this only works if the parts you want to curry are in order. What if I wanted to achieve the following using bind?

```
(b) => (1 + (b / 2))
```

Tried various solutions such as:

```
foo.bind(null, 1, null, 2)
```

Any ideas? Is it possible to accomplish this with vanilla es6?

Comment: with placeholders, you could have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327804/javascript-callback-for-two-functions

Comment: There is a proposal for partial application syntax sugar https://github.com/tc39/proposal-partial-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a wrapper for a reordering of arguments.

```js
const
    foo = (a, b, c) => a + b / c,
    acb = (a, c, b) => foo(a, b, c);

console.log(acb.bind(null, 1, 2)(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I think about two ways to implement this (besides the wrapper from @NinaSholz, which is pretty nice):

#### 1. Using a `curry` function that merges two argument arrays:

```js
const foo = (a, b, c) => a + b / c;

function curry(fn, ...args) {
  return function(...newArgs) {
    const finalArgs = args.map(arg => arg || newArgs.pop());
    return fn(...finalArgs);
  };
}

const curriedFoo = curry(foo, 1, null, 2);

console.log(curriedFoo(4)) // Should print 1 + 4 / 2 = 3
```

Here we are just sending `null` or `undefined` in the place of the parameters we want to skip and in the second call we send those parameters in order

#### 2. Using objects for named parameters

```js
const foo = ({a, b, c}) => a + b / c;

function curry(fn, args) {
  return (newArgs) => fn({ ...args,
    ...newArgs
  });
}

const curriedFoo = curry(foo, {
  a: 1,
  c: 2
});

console.log(curriedFoo({
  b: 4
}));
```

Here we are taking advantage of the `...`(spread) operator and object syntax in the funcion signature to merge two argument objects;

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it in a function

```
const foo = (a, b, c) => (a + (b / c))

_ => foo(1, _, 2) //gives you (b) => (1 + (b / 2))
```