# XSS attack using only alphanumeric inputs

Tags: security, web-applications, xss

Is it possible to do an XSS attack on a web application using only alphanumeric inputs?

Let me also explain my intent here: if it is not possible to do an xss attack using alphanumeric input alone, then I can secure my app using an intercepting filter that rejects all non-alphanumeric inputs.

I understand that such a solution:

- will not allow rich text input
- will not prevent xss attacks where my application renders a page with data from an already tainted data-source

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you implement your filters without bugs, then for web application it will be impossible (for example if you receive only ASCII chars of letters and read them in this format. If you filter according to one format and interpret according to another - it might be problematic).

See [Preventing XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872929/preventing-xss-attacks), and read the OWASP relevant paper: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. You can see in the last reference that usually all the characters **but** the alphanumeric ones are escaped so it is another indication that it should be fine (if you implement it without bugs).