# Html encode in PHP

Tags: php, html-encode

What is the easiest way to Html encode in PHP?

Comment: I think he means the php equivalent to the ASP.NET method "htmlencode". It is used to sanatize the input by replacing characters like '<' with &lt;. He doesn't want to strip them away.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

By encode, do you mean: Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities?

[`htmlspecialchars`](https://secure.php.net/htmlspecialchars) or
[`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

You can also use strip_tags if you want to remove all HTML tags :

[`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Note: this will NOT stop all [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728/will-html-encoding-prevent-all-kinds-of-xss-attacks)

Comment: I am not shure which I have to use. I need this to avoid XSS-atacks.

Comment: Then htmlspecialchars should do the trick. Or use filter_var with the FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS filter.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` > `htmlentities` in most cases. HTML entities for non-ASCII characters should be a thing of the past; just use UTF-8 and drop the characters straight in.

Comment: priority will be for htmlspecialchars in php

Answer (score 5):

Encode.php

```
<h1>Encode HTML CODE</h1>

<form action='htmlencodeoutput.php' method='post'>
<textarea rows='30' cols='100'name='inputval'></textarea>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

htmlencodeoutput.php

```
<?php

$code=bin2hex($_POST['inputval']); 
$spilt=chunk_split($code,2,"%");
$totallen=strlen($spilt);
 $sublen=$totallen-1;
 $fianlop=substr($spilt,'0', $sublen);
$output="<script>
document.write(unescape('%$fianlop'));
</script>";

?> 
<textarea rows='20' cols='100'><?php echo $output?> </textarea>
```

You can encode HTML like this .

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $str = "This is some <b>bold</b> text.";
    echo htmlspecialchars($str);
?>
```

Comment: Why "try this"?  This is not a very generous/informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for hours, and I tried almost everything suggested. 
This worked for almost every entity :

```
$input = "āžšķūņrūķīš ○ àéò ∀∂∋ ©€ ♣♦ ↠ ↔↛ ↙ ℜ℞";


echo htmlentities($input, ENT_HTML5  , 'UTF-8');
```

result :

```
&amacr;&zcaron;&scaron;&kcedil;&umacr;&ncedil;r&umacr;&kcedil;&imacr;&scaron; &cir; &agrave;&eacute;&ograve; &forall;&part;&ReverseElement; &copy;&euro; &clubs;&diamondsuit; &twoheadrightarrow; &harr;&nrarr; &swarr; &Rfr;&rx;rx;
```