# Prevent HTML character codes from being rendered in textarea

Tags: php, sql, textarea, character-codes

Is it possible to display HTML character codes stored in a text field in SQL to a textarea without rendering them as their appropriate character?  i wasnt & to show up as &amp; (the way it's stored in the table).  Or is their a way I should be storing the HTML so I won't need to worry about this?

(site is using PHP)

Comment: Sorry, your typo renders the question unclear: Your database is storing "&" and you want "&" to show up in the textarea, or your database is storing "&amp;" and you want "&amp;" to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can use the function htmlspecialchars ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php ):

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new;
?>
```

and it will render:

```
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

if you want decode them back you just use the function htmlspecialchars_decode

```
<?php
$str = '<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>';

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had actually figured this out a few minutes after I posted the question, but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called HTML Encoding; every modern language has a facility in its  library for doing that, such as the htmlspecialchars function in PHP. For more PHP information, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873793/html-encode-in-php).

You should also make sure that you're properly sanitizing the inputs, even against *multiple rounds* of HTML decoding; otherwise you'll be susceptible to [CSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) (Cross Site Scripting) attacks.