# Regex for converting text links to <a href=""> tags breaks in a certain use case

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex code:

```
$hike_description = nl2br($hike_description);
//$hike_description = str_replace(array('\n','\r'),'',$hike_description);

//Convert all urls to links
$hike_description = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $hike_description);
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^\s]+)#i';
$replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
$hike_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hike_description);
```

It has worked 100% of the time....until now.

In this page the code didn't work for the first time. Specifically, it didn't place the " at the end of the link so the link kept going down the rest of the page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=209

You see how the link from the middle of the page extends all the way to the bottom and is not closed?

Any clue why that might have happened this time and not any other time?

Thanks!

ps - this is the HTML that ends up on the page:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=little+river+canyon+center&fb=1&gl=us&hq=little+river+canyon+center&hnear=0x888a614b2e7272e5%3A0x913a5fafeec714d6%2CCentre%2C+AL&ei=GBsFTtedF8vUgAfex6zNAQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CAQQtgM<br" target="_blank">http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=little+river+canyon+center&fb=1&gl=us&hq=little+river+canyon+center&hnear=0x888a614b2e7272e5%3A0x913a5fafeec714d6%2CCentre%2C+AL&ei=GBsFTtedF8vUgAfex6zNAQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CAQQtgM<br</a> />
```

Comment: I added the html to the bottom of my question, but it is also breaking the question :))))))  The way it appears isn't how I pasted it!!!

Comment: can we see the input, not the output - you've shown us that already with the webpage you linked

Comment: yes, we need to see the URL before you do any PHP handling on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression expects the URL to include all characters up to the next space character.  Immediately following the URL was an html `<br />` tag and the next space seen by your regex was the space before the `/>` in that tag. So it thought the URL also included the `<br` at the beginning of that tag.  When the closing `</a>` was added, it was placed inside a `<br />` tag and therefore was invalidated.

For a quick fix to this specific problem, try changing your regex to look for the `<` character as well as a space to be a URL terminator:

```
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^<\s]+)#i';
                                                         --------^^^----
```

---

**EDIT** I think this is the real source of the problem:

Another possibility is to call `nl2br()` after doing the text replacement rather than before.  That `<br />` tag might have been a newline character beforehand.  The newline would have been interpreted as a space by your regex and the regex replacement wouldn't have choked.

Comment: @Michael I just added the < character to the regext, but it didn't quite work.  Where did I go wrong in this?  Was the problem more the code that encoded this and put this into the db?  Is that the real culprit?  Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik I think where you went wrong (thinking about it more) is that you called `nl2br()` before doing the text replacement.  If there was a newline at the end of that URL, it got converted into a `<br />` and then your regex choked.

Comment: @Michael should I try to put the nl2br after the regex stuff?

Comment: @Genadinik yes give that a try with your original regex.

Comment: @Michael just tried it with original and the new way, but it didn't work wither way :(

Comment: @Genadinik Have a look at the text block before doing any processing on it. Does the URL indeed end in a newline?  Try the whole thing without calling `nl2br()` at all to at least verify if it's causing the problem.

Comment: @Michael just tried it without the nl2br and its still broken.  So it isn't the nl2br.

Comment: By the way, I just pasted the html from my page to the bottom of my question, but it also broke the question :) - what appears at the bottom there isn't exactly what I pasted :)

Answer (score 1):

The link is ending in `<br`. This starts a tag, but you never close it. It also "eats" the `</a>` that is supposed to close the opening `<a>`. You need to escape your input before putting it to the page.

Note that you'd probably want to escape other characters, such as `&`. You may want to check the answer to this question:

- [Html encode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873793/html-encode-in-php)

specifically, this page:

- http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Do you mean the problem is more about how I put things into the db rather what happens when I get them out of there?

Comment: It's probably not DB-related - whatever you put on a page should be escaped as per the above links. So, if you want to put `<` in HTML, you should instead put `&lt;`. Try this in bare HTML (e.g. put `<a href="#">Hello <small> world</a>` and you'll see what I mean - this has nothing to do with things outside HTML).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your pattern to:

```
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^\s<.]+)#i';
```

The problem is that your regular expression assumes that the link ends when a space is encountered, but in this particular case it ends with the left-angular bracket that is the start of the 
 tag

Comment: @Genadinik: sorry that didn't help you but I didn't actually try to execute it. I think it should work but perhaps there might be something that's conflicting in [^\s<.], might be the dot. Can you try removing it?