# Convert UTF-8 text to ASCII in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding

This code outputs UTF-8:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding("ø")
```

And this code outputs ASCII:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding("&#248;");
```

So, how do you convert UTF-8 to ASCII? For example: convert `ø`  to  `&#248`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html encode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873793/html-encode-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&#248;` is an *HTML entity*. It uses only ASCII characters, so it's detected as ASCII, yes. You just need to HTML encode your text:

```
echo htmlentities('ø', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

This will output `&oslash;`, but it's an equivalent named HTML entity.

I'm going out on a limb though and suggest that you don't really understand what you want exactly. Maybe you should read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities to achieve what you looking for

```
$myVar = 'ø';

$val = htmlentities($myVar);
echo $myVar;
// ø
echo mb_detect_encoding($myVar);
// UTF-8

echo $val;
// &oslash;
echo mb_detect_encoding($val);
//ASCII
```