# Can a user break out of <textarea> tag maliciously?

Tags: php, textarea, xss, code-injection

Can a user break out of `<textarea>` tag maliciously?

For example:

`post form contains:`

```
 <form action='post.php' method='post'>
      <textarea name='content'></textarea>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
 </form>
```

`post.php` stores `htmlentities($content)` in the database.

Now the user wants to edit his post, he clicks 'edit' and retrieves the edit form except this time the code is decoded and injected in, for editing purposes.

`edit form contains:`

```
 <form action='edit.php' method='post'>
      <textarea name='content'><?=html_entity_decode($content);?></textarea>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
 </form>
```

is it possible for the user to break out of the textarea tags, seeing as the content has now been decoded back into normal html. Also should one store `htmlentities($content)` in the database or simply raw html, then, encode on the display page - what are the SQL dangers of that technique?

I have tried `</textarea>`, `<!-- --></>`. To be honest I'm not to familiar with XSS attacks but I usually know how to prevent from them.

In this case can someone break out of the `<textarea></textarea>` tags?

Comment: Yes, with your current code he can break out of the textarea and inject whatever HTML he wants to because when producing the output, you're decoding the entities.

Comment: also where to en-code and decode should have been answered already on stackoverflow. please use the search for all your interrelated questions first.

Comment: Are you looking for material like this probably? [Will HTML Encoding prevent all kinds of XSS attacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/53728/367456)

Comment: Turns out when storing the information in htmlentities and retrieving into the textarea is A okay.