# Is my method completely secure for xss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xss

I have a chatting website and I wanna know if it is XSS secure. Let me explain what is my method.

I use this JQuery code to add new messages to screen that are incoming from ajax request:

```
$("#message").prepend(req.msg);
```

I know this is vulnerable but messages on DB are encoded. So when I send that payload message:

```
<text>TEST</test>
```

It stored on database as encoded:

```
&lt;text&gt;TEST&lt;/test&gt;
```

I know a scenario that is bypassing .htmlentities() function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222/6791875) answer. Shortly:

```
 <input value=<%= HtmlEncode(somevar) %> id=textbox>
```

If we send `a onclick=alert(document.cookie)` input to this html code, it will become:

```
<input value=a onclick=alert(document.cookie) id=textbox>
```

So in this scenario, encoding `< > ; &` characters can't save us. But I didn't write my code like this so I think I'm secure from that vulnerabilty. My server responds a JSON like this:

```
..."msg" : "<tr><td><b>user:<\b> &lt;text&gt;TEST&lt;/test&gt;<\td><\tr>",...
```

And I directly .prepend() the "msg" data into page. I think this is fully secure. Hacker must use `< > ; &` characters to XSS. I am also encoding `\` as `\\`. But maybe I am missing something. Is that fully secure ?

Comment: I wouldn't store HTML-escaped data in the database, I would just insert it in the page using a text parser instead of a HTML parser. And I would wrap all attribute values in quotes, and escape quotes in the inserted content.

Comment: I am sorry but what wolud you "insert" in the page? Are you suggesting storing messages unescaped then escape them in runtime before printing? Does it changes anything?

Comment: For example, `$("#message").prepend(document.createTextNode(req.msg));` will prepend a text node instead of parsing `req.msg` as HTML.

Comment: In this case if `req.msg` contains html tags that would trigger an XSS.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because `document.createTextNode` escapes HTML automatically. There's still a vulnerability though :) Look for my answer.

Comment: You should only store the text of the message in the database and then set the text on an element with $.text().

Comment: can I add an img tag? if so I can do an img tag that links to an svg document that has onclick elements that executes javascript. or I can add a base64 encoded svg element. How are you going to stop that?

Comment: To add tags you have to use < and > . When you typed these characters and send a message, I encode them as &lt and &gt and store in databese. So you can't use tags directly. Thats what I am searching. I encoded tags and \ character but maybe there are some characters that I should encode too.

Answer (score 1):

<s>No. It's not. The way the data is transported makes it possible for someone to input unescaped HTML tags. Say that someone posted this payload:</s>

```
\u003cscript\u003ealert(1)\u003c/script\u003e
```

This would be entered into the database as-is, because there is nothing for `htmlencode` to escape. However, when it's put in the JSON, and said JSON is **parsed**, it becomes this:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

And executes the malicious code. A better solution would be to encode the raw data for *JSON*, and then use an HTML escapement mechanism client-side.

With the server-side escaping `\` in the JSON, I think that is fully secure.

Comment: You missed something. I encode "\"  to "\\". So the data in server is `\\u003cscript\\u003ealert(1)\\u003c/script\\u003e`.

Comment: You never mentioned that.