# Preventing Cross Site Scripting C#

Tags: c#, xss

Hi I used HPE Fortify to scan my application and it show a cross site scripting vulnerability on my codes.

How do i prevent cross site scripting based on the codes below?

```
LabelErrorResult.Text += "<li>Duplicate selection for sequence " + ddl.SelectedValue + "</li>";
```

Comment: what is the `ddl.SelectedValue`?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728/will-html-encoding-prevent-all-kinds-of-xss-attacks for a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HtmlEncode and then decode it like

```
String unsafevar = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode("ddl.SelectedValue");

LabelErrorResult.Text += "<li>Duplicate selection for sequence " + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(usafevar); + "</li>";
```

For more you can visit msdn 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can mark it correct answer. It is way to thanks at SO @Marcus

Comment: I do not really understand this line of code:

Comment: Response.BinaryWrite(buffer); i got this issue due to xss too, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you need Response.BinaryWrite ?

Comment: If you encode and then decode it, you get the original unsafe code appended.